# Stop browsers asking to resend form data on refresh

Tags: html, firefox, post

I have a form submission via [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29). I submit the form, and all is well, however if I try to reload the new page that the form goes to after submission, I get the "Do you want to resend data" message (Firefox). It might happen in other browsers too, but I'm not sure.

Is there a way to stop this message popping up so I can go ahead and refresh the page? It's not good for production environments - users may submit the same form twice!

Comment: May be I misunderstood the question . Are you asking how to develop such a form ?

Comment: You do not need the `post/redirect/get` pattern anymore. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47247434/4632019)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent form resubmission when page is refreshed (F5 / CTRL+R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320113/how-to-prevent-form-resubmission-when-page-is-refreshed-f5-ctrlr)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to use the the POST-Redirect-GET pattern.

Make your form respond with a redirect to a GET request. 
This way, when the user refreshes the page, it will only resend the GET.

Comment: For example, OrderSubmit comes back with a 403 redirecto to OrderConfirmationView. That when a user hits refresh (or sends the link to a friend, or bookmarks it, etc.), they only refresh the view not the action.

Answer (score 13):

An easy way after `response.sendRedirect` is to reload the page in this way:

```
window.location.href = window.location.pathname;
```

It works for me.

Comment: Could you please elaborate and give more details?

Comment: @Damir: rather than a "reload", this is like going to a new page, except it's the same page. As if you clicked on a link that will send you to the same page you're already on.

Answer (score -1):

If the URL does not have any parameter, use this -

```
window.location = window.location.href + "?rnd=" + Math.random();
```

Or else use this -

```
window.location = window.location.href + "&rnd=" + Math.random();
```

It will work.

Comment: This is a very ugly solution. Adding random numbers to the end of a POST request is probably the worst way of solving the original problem

Comment: @Bojangles - Can you clarify the drawbacks?

Comment: @Bojangles: Even JQuery uses this technique (they use it within their "cache"-Option within $.ajax()-Calls, to prevent that the Ajax-Target-URL is cached). So I don't think that it is the "worst" thing to do. It works and it works as expected. So I think it's a good and easy solution for the problem!

Comment: Why clutter up the URI when you don't have to? There are better solutions above.

Answer (score -3):

It will be a security violation if browsers do that. For example, in credit card processing, the site may charge the user twice.

The only way round is go to the address bar and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It will cause a new request.

Comment: That's why the user is trying to figure out how to prevent it; they don't want to have the form submitted twice.

Comment: Asking the user to do something is not the "only way round". This is simply wrong