# how to disable browser refresh confirmation message [resend cancel] from javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop browsers asking to resend form data on refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327236/stop-browsers-asking-to-resend-form-data-on-refresh)

how to disable browser refresh confirmation message [resend cancel] from javascript .?

Comment: possible duplicate  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327236/stop-browsers-asking-to-resend-form-data-on-refresh/4327270#4327270

Comment: @Madhur: I can't see how that other question has anything to do with scripting (or even programming at all, seems to be a browser configuration question).  This isn't a dupe IMO.

Comment: You don't want to do it with JavaScript. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327236/stop-browsers-asking-to-resend-form-data-on-refresh/4327270#4327270 for how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having the user refresh the entire page, you might consider using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) and provide your own refresh button. It likely will make refreshing quicker as well because the entire page does not have to be reloaded.

Comment: Thanks for your reply idealmachine :) but i am not able to get an nice example of tat :( pls provide me an link to refer :)