# javascript pop-up in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, reload

Is there a way to not show to user a pop-up (To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation ) that was performed earlier. - Resend/Cancel) [image: pop-up]

which is shown when I want to reload an iframe with javascript in Firefox, my code is like this:

```
parent.frames["id_termine"].window.location.reload();
```

I tried with this solution [Reload page for refresh data without retry/cancel prompt](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/55968/Reload-page-for-refresh-data-without-retry-cancel)

but it didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these solutions: [Stop browsers asking to resend form data on refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327236/stop-browsers-asking-to-resend-form-data-on-refresh)

Did the location.href = location.pathname method continue to produce a popup? Or did it load the wrong page / cause a 500 error?

You can't refresh a POST request without triggering that popup. It's a security feature. Redesign your backend to use a GET request for this iframe. If you can't change the backend, try loading the content using ajax and inject the result into the iFrame.