# HTML Form Submit but Prevent While Refreshing Page Resubmiting Form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a simple `form`. I am sending the `form` to same page that has the `form`. However, after every `submit` process, then when I want to refresh the page manually, the browser asks me:

> Do you want to re-send the form?

How can I prevent this?

foo.php

```
<?php echo $_POST['id']; ?>

<form action="foo.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="id" value="">
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: submit your form using ajax

Comment: maybe its duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327236/stop-browsers-asking-to-resend-form-data-on-refresh

Comment: maybe you redirect to another page after you process posted data like **header('Location:success.php');
die();**

Answer (score 0):

check with a condition if the form was posted, process the form and then redirect using javascript.

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST["id"]( {

//do stuff
?>
<script>
location.href=("/");
</script>
<?
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: Check with a condition if the form was submited and then redirect to the same page.

```
if(isset($_POST['button_name_from_form'])) {
  #...code
  header('Location:page.php');
}
```

!! But make sure that header is before any output. !!

Method 2: Ajax